# Why does the substitution $y=vx^m$ solve an Isobaric ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to know how the substitution $y=vx^m$ makes the equation
$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{A(x,y)}{B(x,y)}$ separable.

I am aware that the equation $f(x,y)$ is called isobaric if $f(tx, t^m y)=t^{m-1}f(x,y)$ for some value of $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the substitution, that is:  $$x^{m}\frac{dv}{dx}+mx^{m-1}v=\frac{A(x,vx^{m})}{B(x,vx^{m})}=\frac{x^{m-1}A(1,v)}{B(1,v)}=x^{m-1}C(v)$$
Which rearranges to $$x^{m}dv+\left(mx^{m-1}v-x^{m-1}C(v)\right)dx=0$$
So $$\frac{dv}{mv-C(v)}+\frac{dx}{x}=0$$

Comment: For the third equality have we assumed that the whole of A/B is isobaric with order m?

Comment: Yes, and indeed that seems to be what is meant by the term (if you do a google search for isobaric equations you should be able to find some examples)